# Formalizing "all sets which can be expressed involving only $a$ and $b$ as primitive elements; without involving the empty set, or any singleton sets"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for a definition, stated formally and reasonably short and elementary, to identify the set (or class?) which informally, and only very partially, but (hopefully) suggestively may be sketched as

$$ \Big\{ {\Large{ \{ a, b \}, \, \{ a, {\normalsize{\{ a, b \}}} \}, \, \{ b, {\normalsize{\{ a, b \}}} \}, \, \{ a, b, {\normalsize{\{ a, b \}}} \}, \, \{ a, {\normalsize{ \{ a, { \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \} }} \}, \, \{ b, {\normalsize{ \{ a, { \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \} }} \}, }}$$

$$ {\Large{ \! \{ \! {\normalsize{ \{ a, b \} }}, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \,
\{ a, b, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \, 
\{ a, {\normalsize{ \{ a, b \} }}, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \, \{ b, {\normalsize{ \{ a, b \} }}, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \,}}$$

$$ {\Large{ \! \{ a, b, {\normalsize{ \{ a, b \} }}, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \}  \! , \,
\{ a, {\normalsize{ \{ { b, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \, \dots, \{ a, {\normalsize{ \{ { a, b, \scriptsize{ \{ a, b \}}} \! \} }} \! \} \! , \, \dots }} \Big\}$$

In (other) words:
I'm seeking a formal expression for the collection of all sets which can be expressed involving only $a$ and $b$ as primitive elements; without involving the empty set, and without involving any [singleton sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3757911/three-definitions-of-singleton-set).

(A solution should be given without any [ellipses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis#Plural), of course; and, ideally, not involve the symbol $\infty$ or equivalent, either.

However, I'm not necessarily looking for an explicit expression; but I'd be satisfied with an implicit formulation, i.e. with a statement of sufficient conditions to be satisfied by the collection that I mean.

Whichever applicable formulation comfortably fits on one line will be accepted right away!)

Comment: Do you want only sets that can be written in a *finite* way like this or do you also allow infinite sets?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: _"[...] or do you also allow infinite sets?"_ -- I'm looking to express exactly specificly one inifinite set. (The ellipsis in my very partial suggestive formula is meant to indicate: "and so on, without any finite end". (Doesn't it?))

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: _"[...] or do you also allow infinite sets?"_ -- Reconsidering your question -- sure: **each finite as well as each infinite set** (which can be expressed involving only $a$ and $b$ as primitive elements; without involving the empty set, or any singleton sets) ought to be included. (Possible complications relating therefore to "the set that I mean including itself" should be ignored, please ...)

Comment: all of your examples include both $a$ and $b$,  is this intended?

Comment: @Alan: _"all of your examples include both $a$ and $b$"_ -- Indeed, that's what happened for the few examples which I tried to list systematically as "very partial suggestive formula". _"is this intended?"_ -- At least, it's not an explicit requirement. However: Can you express **any set at all** which includes only one primitive element, say $a$, without including/involving the empty set, nor any singleton set?? (If so, it should indeed be included in the collection whose formal description I seek; and so on.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to define this (in the context of ZFC, say) is probably by transfinite recursion.  Define a sequence of sets $S_\alpha$ indexed by the ordinals recursively as follows:

- If $\alpha=\beta+1$ is a successor ordinal, then $S_\alpha$ is the union of $S_\beta$ and the set of all subsets of $S_\beta\cup\{a,b\}$ with at least two elements.
- If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $S_\alpha=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}S_\beta$.

The class you are looking for is then the union $\bigcup_{\alpha\in Ord}S_\alpha$.

(More generally, a recursion like this is how you can construct the smallest class closed under certain operations.  In this case, the operations are taking subsets which have at least two elements and can also have $a$ or $b$ as elements.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eric. The proposal is certainly not as elementary as I had been hoping; the explicit appeal to a _"limit ordinal"_ surely resembles invoking "$\infty$" which I had been asking to avoid. Consider by comparison, and as a guiding example, the (explicit, naive) definition of the power set of any given set ... Also, I'm not quite sure about the "base case" (induction start) of your proposal ...

Comment: The "base case" is just the limit ordinal $\alpha=0$ where you get $S_0=\emptyset$ since there are no ordinals $\beta<0$.

Comment: Eric Wofsey: _"The "base case" is just [...] $S_0 = \emptyset$"_ -- Alright; then, IIUC, the ind. step requires to consider the union of sets $S_0$ and $\{ a, b \}$, i.e.
$$S_0 \cup \{ a, b \} = \emptyset \cup \{ a, b \} = \{ a, b \}.$$
From this make a set of all (not necessarily proper) subsets with at least two elements (that's precisely only the set $\{ a, b \}$), resulting in $\{ \{a, b\} \}$, and then form the union with $S_0$ to obtain $$S_1 := \{ \{a, b\} \} \cup S_0 = \{ \{a, b\} \} \cup \emptyset = \{ \{a, b\} \}.$$ Good enough, +1. But my hope for a simpler expression remains ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathcal J$ denote any mathematical object satisfying the following conditions:

$ (\{ a, b \} \in \mathcal J) \text{ and }$
$ (\forall X \in \mathcal J : (\{ a, X \} \in \mathcal J) \text{ and } (\{ b, X \} \in \mathcal J)) \text{ and }$
$ (\forall S \subseteq \mathcal J : ((\exists Y \in S : (\exists Z \in S : Z \ne Y)) \implies (S \in \mathcal J)) \text{ and }$
$(\forall \mathcal K : $
$\qquad ((\{ a, b \} \in \mathcal K) \text{ and }$
$\qquad (\forall X \in \mathcal K : (\{ a, X \} \in \mathcal K) \text{ and } (\{ b, X \} \in \mathcal K)) \text{ and } $
$\qquad (\forall S \subseteq \mathcal K : ((\exists Y \in S : (\exists Z \in S : Z \ne Y)) \implies (S \in \mathcal K))) $
$\qquad \implies (\mathcal J \cap \mathcal K = \mathcal J))). $

I'd suggest that thereby $\mathcal J$ is uniquely identified as the mathematical object sought in the OP question.